# GNU Parallel: How can I reference array elements?

Tags: bash, array, gnu-parallel

This is my case scenario:

```
luis@Balanceador:~$ echo ${array[@]}
a b
luis@Balanceador:~$ echo ${array[1]}
a
luis@Balanceador:~$ echo ${array[2]}
b
luis@Balanceador:~$ parallel echo ${array[]} ::: 1 2
-bash: ${array[]}: bad substitution
luis@Balanceador:~$ parallel echo ${array[{}]} ::: 1 2
-bash: {}: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{}")
luis@Balanceador:~$ parallel echo ${array[{1}]} ::: 1 2
-bash: {1}: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{1}")
luis@Balanceador:~$ parallel echo ${array[{#}]} ::: 1 2
-bash: {#}: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{#}")
```

How can I reference the individuals elements of some array on GNU Parallel?

Sure this is an easy one, but I have not been able to find it on the manual.

This question has been made to answer [this other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/gnu-parallel-how-can-i-store-the-results-of-multiple-commands-on-a-variable), but, after asking it, I considered they were two different questions.

Comment: `parallel echo ::: "${array[@]}"`

Comment: Well, thanks you for answering, @don_crissti , but my original idea was a bit more complex. I have edited the original question to reflect, but you can see the main idea here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/gnu-parallel-how-can-i-store-the-results-of-multiple-commands-on-a-variable

Comment: I saw your other question. Assuming you were able to do that, `gnu parallel` starts sub-shells... how do you expect to access those variables if they're defined in sub-shells ? Run `seq 3 | parallel echo $$` (this is the shell that runs `parallel`) and then run `seq 3 | parallel echo \$\$` (these are sub-shells started by `parallel`)...

Comment: I think you are right, @don_crissti . Maybe the only way will be to store the results inside files. Thanks you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it looks easy, it is really very hard.

Jobs started by GNU Parallel are not started inside the same shell as GNU Parallel is run from. So it looks like this:

```
bash[1]---perl(running parallel)---bash[2]
```

$array is defined in bash[1] but you want to use it in bash[2]. It is impossible to do completely (i.e. if you want write access to the array), but we *can* make a *copy* of $array available:

```
env_parallel 'echo ${array[{}]}' ::: 1 2
```

[`env_parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/env_parallel.html) (introduced in GNU Parallel 20140822) copies the entire environment of bash[1] to bash[2] (so your environment has to be kinda small) where it is initiated before the job is run.

`env_parallel` is quite unstable, so if you find bugs, please report them.

Comment: What is `env_parallel`? How does it copy arrays (you can't pass arrays through the environment directly)?

Comment: @Giles env_parallel is a fairly recent development and is still not production quality. Please read `man env_parallel` and `man parallel_design` and get back if that does not answer your question.

Comment: `No manual entry for env_parallel`. I see, not yet in Debian unstable. I'm still confused as to what it does: you say that it copies the *environment* but then your examples show it copying *shell variables*, aliases and functions. I guess this is a documentation bug report: “environment” already has a technical meaning in this context and it's really confusing to use it with a different meaning. I suggest calling this “context”, and explaning what is considered context (what about shell options, for example?).

Comment: Maybe you are right about the wording. Can you come up with an authoritative source that defines the difference between shell environment and context? The goal is to copy the whole environment, but that will of course never be possible 100%  (e.g. $$ will never work), but shell options for Bash will be supported in next version.

Comment: “Environment” in this context appears to refer to a very specific technical meaning: the set of [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). “[Context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_(computing))” is a more conceptual term that would fit and that has no existing specific meaning in Unix shells and processes. This needs an explanation either way, but at least with “context” there's no contradiction between meanings, only a clarification.

Comment: @Gilles Your link links to environment _variables_ - not environment. There has never been any disagreement on environment _variables_. The question is whether environment covers more than environment _variables_. E.g. $PATH has great influence on what commands you can execute. The same can be said for functions and aliases. $PATH is undoubtly part of the environment. Your link should state why functions and aliases are not part of the environment.

Comment: Your link does neither confirm this nor deny this. Better reference is needed before I am convinced that environment _variables_ == environment and not just a subset of environment.

The link about context, OTOH, is clearly not applicable: It is about contexts as in context switches between processes, and this is a concept very different from shell environments.

Comment: Authoritative source: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ 

A shell execution environment consists of the following: [...] 

Shell parameters that are set by variable assignment [...]
Shell functions; [...]
Options turned on at invocation or by set [...]
Shell aliases; [...].

I was a bit surprised how much is regarded part of the environment, and env_parallel will never be able to copy everything.