# GNU Parallel: How can I store the results of multiple commands on a variable?

Tags: gnu-parallel

> This question comes from [this other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292272/gnu-parallel-how-can-i-reference-array-elements). I thought it was proper to make
>   another, rather than editing the original one.

This is my example case scenario (an array with two commands I would like to execute):

```
luis@Balanceador:~$ echo ${cmds[@]}
ls -la echo 'hola'
luis@Balanceador:~$ echo ${cmds[0]}
ls -la
luis@Balanceador:~$ echo ${cmds[1]}
echo 'hola'
```

I would like to **store the results** of each command in a variable using GNU Parallel, like in:

```
luis@Balanceador:~$ value0="$(${cmds[0]})"
luis@Balanceador:~$ printf "$value0"
total 36
drwxr-xr-x   2 luis  luis   512 Jun 26 23:09 .
drwxr-xr-x  13 luis  luis   512 Jun 26 22:50 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 luis  luis  1554 Jun 26 18:31 MostrarDatosRed.config
-rwxr-xr-x   1 luis  luis  8335 Jun 26 23:44 MostrarDatosRed.sh
-rwxr-xr-x   1 luis  luis    98 Jun 26 23:10 TestParallel.sh
-rw-r--r--   1 luis  luis    19 Jun 26 18:01 instrucciones.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 luis  luis     2 Jun 26 22:06 prueba.txt
```

and...

```
luis@Balanceador:~$ value1="$(${cmds[1]})"
luis@Balanceador:~$ printf "$value1"
'hola'
```

How can I do this using **GNU Parallel**?

Comment: This very much looks like a problem that's crying out for a 'map-reduce' solution, and is stretching bash scripting somewhat - Python is more than capable of tackling this sort of problem in a more capable way, for example.

Answer (score 2):

I know of no elegant way to do this. Sopalajo comes with one way to do it. Here is another that does not use tempfiles but which deals wrongly if the output contains \377 (ascii 255):

```
IFS="$(printf "\377")" arr=($(parallel 'echo foo {} ;printf "\377"' ::: a b c))
```

Comment: Well, it adds some `\377` character to the end of each array's element, what `echo "${arr[n]}"` yields on screen like some sort of `\n`. But, as long as there is no clean solution, this one could save the day.

Answer (score 2):

GNU Parallel now includes `parset`:

```
$ parset arr echo foo {} ::: a b c
$ echo ${arr[0]}
foo a
$ echo ${arr[1]}
foo b
$ echo ${arr[2]}
foo c

$ parset v1,v2,v3 echo foo {} ::: a b c
$ echo $v3
foo c

$ parset "v1 v2 v3" echo foo {} ::: a b c
$ echo $v3
foo c
```

Comment: This looks great. However I cannot find how to install `parset` on macOS. Does anyone have any advice? (I tried brew and google)

Comment: Install GNU Parallel. Then run `env_parallel --install`. Finally start another shell (or logout/login). This should activate both `env_parallel` and `parset`.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: store the results in several **files**.
Example:

```
parallel {1} '>' comando{#}.txt ::: "${cmds[@]}"
```

Results seem to be OK:

```
luis@Balanceador:~$ ls -la comando*
-rw-r--r--  1 luis  luis  532 Jun 27 00:33 comando1.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 luis  luis    5 Jun 27 00:33 comando2.txt
luis@Balanceador:~$ cat comando1.txt
total 40
drwxr-xr-x   2 luis  luis   512 Jun 27 00:33 .
drwxr-xr-x  13 luis  luis   512 Jun 26 22:50 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 luis  luis     0 Jun 27 00:33 comando1.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 luis  luis     5 Jun 27 00:33 comando2.txt
luis@Balanceador:~$ cat comando2.txt
hola
```