# Store results of multiple commands in a specific position in an array

Tags: gnu-parallel

The `parset` utility allow to store output of commands in a variable or any array.However i want to store output in specific array indexes.

```
$ parset arr echo foo {} ::: a b c
$ echo ${arr[0]}
foo a
$ echo ${arr[1]}
foo b
$ echo ${arr[2]}
foo c
```

How can i specify the array indexes in the command.Let assume i want to store the values in `${arr[4]}` , `${arr[5]}` , `${arr[6]}`

Comment: Can you complete your topic with output of `parset` utility and type what do you want to store in array?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/gnu-parallel-how-can-i-store-the-results-of-multiple-commands-on-a-variable#

Comment: @user2650277, strange, `parset arr echo foo {} ::: a b c` gives me `parset: command not found` on `GNU parallel 20141022`. It's a new feature, I suppose

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes you need to compile parallel from source with latest version and do the installation https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parset.html#Installation

Comment: `parset` was introduced in 20170422.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to 20171122 or do the below.

The change is trivial: Simply disable the check for valid variable name (in `env_parallel.bash`):

```
#    echo "$_parset_name" |                                                        
#       perl -ne 'chomp;for (split /[, ]/) {                                       
#           if(not /^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*$/) {                                   
#                print STDERR "parset: Error: $_ is an invalid variable name.\n";  
#                print STDERR "parset: Error: Variable names must be letter follow\
ed by letters or digits.\n";                                                       
#                $exitval = 255;                                                   
#            }                                                                     
#        }                                                                         
#        exit $exitval;                                                            
#        ' || return 255
```

and do:

```
. env_parallel.bash
parset 'arr[4],arr[5],arr[6]' echo foo {} ::: a b c
echo ${arr[6]}
```